# Unable to limit or change user Input when using setFieldsValue in ant Design Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to limit the user input as one enters some value in the
form item input field. I want the user to just add limited characters and 
after that the user is not able to type any characters and additional
characters are replaced with `''`.

So far Im using Ant Design Forms in my react application. I am not handling form data manually since Im using `Form.create` and `getFieldsDecorator` which will collect and validate Form data automatically as stated in the documentation.

The documentation says to use `setFieldsValue` to set control's value programmaticly.

In my case it doesn't seem to work. I am mentioning only the important parts of code for the sake of simplicity here.

```
    const Modal = ({
      visible,
      modalType,
      closeModal,
      companiesList,
      cohortsList,
      employeeDetail,
      inProgressAction,
      success,
      ...props
    }) => {
      const [editForm, setEditForm] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);

      const handleChange = name => event => {
        const value = event.target.value.slice(0,10);
        setEditForm(prevEditForm => ({
          ...prevEditForm,
          [name]: value,
        }));

        props.form.setFieldsValue({ [name]: value }); // This doesn't limit the value to 10 and the user is still able to enter more than 10 charavters
      };

      return (
        <Modal
          title="Create New Employee"
          visible={visible}
          onOk={handleOk}
          onCancel={closeModal}
          destroyOnClose
          centered
          footer={[
            <Button
              key="cancel"
              onClick={closeModal}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>,
            <Button
              key="submit"
              type="primary"
              onClick={handleOk}
              disabled={!isSubmitEnabled()}
              loading={inProgressAction === 'add'}
            >
              Add Employee
            </Button>,
          ]}
        >
          <Spin
            spinning={props.loadingCompanies || props.loadingCohorts}
            className="mk_dotted_spinner"
            size="small"
          >
            <Form {...formItemLayout}>
              <Form.Item label="Name">
                {props.form.getFieldDecorator('fullName', {
                  initialValue: editForm.fullName,
                  rules: [
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: 'Please input employee name!',
                    },
                  ],
                })(
                  <Input
                    className="mk_input_secondary"
                    onChange={handleChange('fullName')}
                  />
                )}
              </Form.Item>
            </Form>
          </Spin>
        </Modal>
      );
    };

    export default Form.create({ name: 'employeeForm' })(Modal);
```

The expected behavior is that user cannot enter more than 10 characters in the field since I am setting `setFieldsValue` and slicing the input but the user is still able to enter input. Somehow, my understanding is since `getFieldsDecorator` is controlling the form I am unable to limit the input. Is there some workaround for this? I have been looking at the documentation regarding `setFieldsValue` but couldn't find anything except this line

`Use setFieldsValue to set other control's value programmaticly.`

Which is **Not** working. Here is the documentation [link](https://ant.design/components/form/), I have been following.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put maxLength={10} in the input tag

```
<Input
  maxLength={10}
  className="mk_input_secondary"
  onChange={handleChange('fullName')}
/>
```